# Spacing between grid areas

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a 2 column grid layout where column 1 runs down the left side of the page. column 2 fills the rest of the page. I'm trying to create spacing just between column 1 and 2 only. I have 10 items  in the container. item 1 is by itself in column1 in the grid, the rest is in column2

I've tried using grid-gap, grid-gap columns, margins and padding. grid-gap creates spacing around everything in the grid. The rest doesn't work

```
item1 {
grid-area: 1 / 1 / 7 / 1;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 30px;
 }

 .grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 350px auto auto auto auto;
grid-gap: 20px;
width: 80%;
margin-bottom: 150px;
 }

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1">
      <P>Buyers</P>
      <P>Sellers</P>
      <P>All Properties</P>
      <P>New Properties</P>
      <P>Active Status</P>
      <P>Pending</P>
      <P>Contingent</P>
      <P>Sold</P>
      <P>Feedback</P>
    </div>
```

Actual results are the grid does the spacing automatically and correctly. I would like to add space between the two columns.

Comment: 5 columns, actually (mentioned only to avoid additional confusion)

Comment: It is 5 columns, column 1 is one column while the rest of the data is evenly spaced across the other 4 columns. I'm trying to put a space between column 1 & the rest.

Comment: Then I'd suggest a **six** column grid with column 2 being reserved for this extra "space" you seem to require. Or make the 1st column wider and use `padding-right` for space inside `item1`

Comment: Thank you, column 2 being left blank should work. Can each container be spaced individually?